# InvalidOperationException on Editing SaveChange ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, invalidoperationexception, savechanges

Here is my code for HTTPPost Edit action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var PeopleUpdateToDate = db.People.Find(id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(PeopleUpdateToDate, "", new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "Age", "Address", "Interests", "FilePath" }))
    { 
        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            if (PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar))
            {
                db.FilePaths.Remove(PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar));
            }
            var avatar = new FilePath
            {
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                FileType = FileType.Avatar
            };                    

            PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths = new List<FilePath> { avatar };
        }                

        db.Entry(PeopleUpdateToDate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");           

    }      
    return View(PeopleUpdateToDate);
}
```

And I got InvalidOperationException as

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I did some search, looks like I should change

```
db.FilePaths.Remove(PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar));
```

to

```
db.FilePaths.DeleteObject(PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar));
```

However, DelectObject is not an option for me.  Please help, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to delete and then add a new `avatar` (as opposed to just updating the `FileName` property of the existing one)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of this error could be hidden in that logic:

```
            if (PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar))
            {
                db.FilePaths.Remove(PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.First(f => f.FileType 
                  == FileType.Avatar));
            }
            var avatar = new FilePath
            {
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                FileType = FileType.Avatar
            };                    

            PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths = new List<FilePath> { avatar };
```

So, let's suppose that your `PeopleUpdateToDate` object has a few FilePaths items (more than just one). In this code you remove from your FiletPaths table just one FilePath item

```
        if (PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar))
        {
            db.FilePaths.Remove(PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar));
        }
```

But then you clear your `PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths` list. So, if there was more than one FilePath item in that list, then all items except the one that you have removed will have their foreign keys PeopleId == null.

Maybe it could be better to use something like this

```
PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths.Add(avatar);
```

instead of

```
PeopleUpdateToDate.FilePaths = new List<FilePath> { avatar };
```

I hope I've understood your idea right